# configure aws lambda and api gateway to return binary data for image/avif content-type

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, avif

There's no shortage of questions and blog posts about binary data using aws lambda and api gateway, but surprisingly I haven't been able to find anything related to AVIF images. This is important because of [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1123919) in chromium. Essentially the chrome team recently added `"image/avif"` to the beginning of its `Accept` header for images, and that's causing my endpoint to return the base64 string of an image rather than the binary data. If I repeat the same request using curl and remove the `"image/avif"` from the `Accept` header, I get the binary data. Concretely:

- `accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9` **yields *binary* data**
- `accept: image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8` **yields *base64* data** (and the image is broken in the webpage)
- `accept: image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8` **yields *binary* data**

From the discussion in the chromium thread, it seems that the solution is to update my endpoint to respond with the appropriate binary data when the `Accept` header begins with `"image/avif"`. However, this is proving difficult for me. The closest I've come is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68061735/7987987). I've followed those steps to update my API gateway config but I'm still getting base64 data when the `Accept` header begins with `"image/avif"`. And I haven't found any posts specifically referring to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out that guide I linked to in the post had all the necessary steps, but the "save changes" button in the API Gateway dashboard doesn't actually deploy your changes. You have to go to `Resources` > `Actions` > `Deploy API` to make the changes live.