# Image Not Showing In AWS Lambda Response

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trouble returning an image from AWS Lambda.

I have a nodejs lambda that gets an image (png) from s3 and uses sharp to resize it. It then returns this as a response.

But when i query this lamba via the API Gateway endpoint, it does show.

[image]

[image]

I do not understand why because I have checked the base64 string that is generated/used as the body and it converts fine to a png. The response also has the correct content-type header.

Below is the code from my lamba. The original image is just a response from s3 getObject.

```
// create a new image using provided dimensions.
const result = await Sharp(originalImage.Body, { failOnError: true })
    .resize(width, height)
    .rotate()
    .toBuffer();

// return created image as a response.
return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: result.toString('base64'),
    isBase64Encoded: true,
    headers: {
        'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
        'Content-Type': originalImageMime,
        'x-amz-meta-content-type': originalImageMime,
        'Cache-Control': DEFAULT_CACHE_HEADER,
        'Age': 0
    }
};
```

Is there anything I'm missing to get the image to show in the GET request? or is there a setting on AWS API Gateway/lambda stopping this?

Comment: Did you configure [API Gateway Lambda proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html)?

Comment: @jarmod Yes, I created the API Gateway via the Lambda trigger. If I click on the endpoint in the Gateway, the Integration Response is disabled and says "Proxy integrations cannot be configured to transform responses."

Comment: I suspect you need to toggle the "Use Lambda Proxy integration" checkbox on the integration request configuration.

Comment: @jarmod is there any reason using this as a proxy would cause this issue? As soon as I make it not a proxy, I have to put all the manual param mappings and it doesnt really work. Is the proxy not just routing it to be controlled by the lambda?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to this post [Return image from aws lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67876045/return-image-from-aws-lambda-function)

I found out that I needed to make a Model under the API Gateway for the response type (image/png) and it worked!